# Hashtable get request returning null instead of requested data

Tags: java

So I have this .csv file with each line having the same formating key:data; and the scanner uses the ";" as the delimeter, and the ":" is used to split the key from the data. When I print the hashtable it returns all the values, when I call the very first value it works, but every other value returns null despite it showing as declared when I print the hashtable. I have no clue why this is, I've tried every variable, I've tried copy and pasting the key to try, yet no matter what I only get null if it's not the first variable.

Source code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Hashtable<String, String> Cereals = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Cereal.csv"));
    scanner.useDelimiter(";");
    while (scanner.hasNext())
    {
      String[] args1 = (scanner.next()).split(":"); //Splits the information by :
      Cereals.put(args1[0],args1[1]);
    }
    scanner.close()
    System.out.println(Cereals.get("100% Natural Bran");
  }
```

Portion of .csv:

```
100% Bran:C/70/4/1/130/10/5/6/280/25/3/1/0.33/68.402973;
100% Natural Bran:C/120/3/5/15/2/8/8/135/0/3/1/1/33.983679;
All-Bran:C/70/4/1/260/9/7/5/320/25/3/1/0.33/59.425505;
All-Bran with Extra Fiber:C/50/4/0/140/14/8/0/330/25/3/1/0.5/93.704912;
Almond Delight:C/110/2/2/200/1/14/8/-1/25/3/1/0.75/34.384843;
```

Returns null for 100% Natural Bran, and the others. However returns the value for 100% Bran.

It's supposed to return the value of the requested key.

Comment: Note: As described in the documentation, don't use `Hashtable` in new code. Use `HashMap` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because, except for the first key, the rest is storing not only the string, but the `\r\n` value

`\r\n100% Natural Bran`. That is the real key being stored in the HashTable, not `100% Natural Bran`. The same happens with the next keys.

To solve it, you should `trim()` the key before putting it

```
Cereals.put(args1[0].trim(), args1[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is that the line delimiters are not handled properly and appended to the key names.  So it may be needed:

- fix the delimiter of the scanner: `scanner.useDelimiter(";\r?\n?");`
- or to trim the keys when putting them to the hashtable: `Cereals.put(args1[0].trim(),args1[1]);`

Then the value of `100% Natural Bran` can be retrieved successfully:

```
System.out.println(Cereals.get("100% Natural Bran"));
// C/120/3/5/15/2/8/8/135/0/3/1/1/33.983679
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I found was using "hasNext" and "next", by replacing it with "hasNextLine" and "nextLine" the issue was solved. Thank you to everyone who helped me though!